# NULL values reading from excel file

Tags: vb.net

i am not getting the integer values in dataset while reading from an excel files
the field which is integer will be showing as NULL.wht should i do to solve this probelm?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OleDB (ADO.NET) then you need to read this article:
http://blog.lab49.com/archives/196

You will probably find solution to your problem there.

Another issue that you might run into is the 32-bit vs 64-bit. This may not come up on your local machine if you're on 32-bit OS, but you'll see this problem when you deploy your app to a 64-bit OS (i.e. if you have ASP.NET app deploed to IIS on 64-bit Windows).
Below is some more info on the subject, but basically if boils down to the fact that your application will have to target 32-bit only (there's no 64-bit version of Jet)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/45aa44dd-0e6f-42e5-a9d6-9be5c5c8fcd1
How set this up properly on IIS:
http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/general/error-on-64-bit-windows-machines-the-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine.aspx